# i try make upload file using telerik tool with update panel to uplaod file using ajax but it dose not work correctly

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I nead upload file without postback, I want use upload panel to send
data to ashx to save file

```
<telerik:RadScriptManager runat="server" ID="RadScriptManager1" />
<telerik:RadSkinManager ID="RadSkinManager1" runat="server" ShowChooser="true" />
<div class="demo-container size-wide no-bg">
    <telerik:RadAjaxPanel ID="RadAjaxPanel1" runat="server" ClientEvents-OnRequestStart="requestStart"
        LoadingPanelID="LoadingPanel1">
        <div class="uploadPanel">
            <div class="leftPanel">
                <div class="controls first">
                    <span class="label">Nick</span>
                    <br />
                    <telerik:RadTextBox ID="NickTextBox" runat="server"   Skins ="Silk" Width="183px"></telerik:RadTextBox>                        
                </div>                    
                <div class="controls">
                    <span class="label">File(s)</span>
                    <telerik:RadUpload ID="RadUpload1" runat="server" MaxFileInputsCount="2" OverwriteExistingFiles="false"
                        ControlObjectsVisibility="RemoveButtons"  Skins="Silk" AutoPostBack="true"
                        EnableTheming="False">
                    </telerik:RadUpload>
                    <telerik:RadButton ID="Save" runat="server" Text="Save" Skins="Silk" 
                        onclick="Save_Click" AutoPostBack="true">
                    </telerik:RadButton>
                    <asp:Button ID="ButtonSend" EnableTheming="False" OnClick="ButtonSend_Click" runat="server" Skins="Silk" 
                    Text="Save"
                        CssClass="button" ></asp:Button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="rightPanel">
                <div id="UploadedFileLog" class="UploadedFileClass" runat="server">
                    No uploaded files yet.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </telerik:RadAjaxPanel>
    <telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel ID="LoadingPanel1" runat="server" InitialDelayTime="0" Skin="Default">
    </telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel>
    <telerik:RadCodeBlock ID="RadCodeBlock1" runat="server">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js"></script>
    </telerik:RadCodeBlock>
</div>
enter code here
code
```

here we make upload to file but it dose not work with update panel

```
public void ButtonSend_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    UploadedFileLog.InnerHtml = "";

    if (RadUpload1.UploadedFiles.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (Telerik.Web.UI.UploadedFile postedFile in RadUpload1.UploadedFiles)
        {
            UploadedFileLog.InnerHtml += "<b>Uploaded file information</b>: <hr />";
            UploadedFileLog.InnerHtml += "<b>Nick name</b>: " + NickTextBox.Text;

            if (!Object.Equals(postedFile, null))
            {
                string filname = postedFile.FileName;
                string tim = DateTime.Now.Second.ToString() + "-" + DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString() + "-" + DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString() + "-" + DateTime.Now.Day.ToString() + "-" + DateTime.Now.Month.ToString() + "-" + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();
                postedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/files/test/") + tim + "#" + filname);
                if (postedFile.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    UploadedFileLog.InnerHtml += string.Format("<br /><b>Filename</b>: {0}", postedFile.FileName);
                    UploadedFileLog.InnerHtml += string.Format("<br /><b>File Size</b>: {0} bytes", postedFile.ContentLength);
                }
                else
                {
                    UploadedFileLog.InnerHtml += "<br />No uploaded files yet.";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                UploadedFileLog.InnerHtml += "<br />No uploaded files yet.";
            }
        }
    }


}

protected void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UploadedFileLog.InnerHtml = "";
    UploadedFileLog.InnerHtml += RadUpload1.UploadedFiles.Count.ToString();
    if (RadUpload1.UploadedFiles.Count > 0)
    {

        foreach (Telerik.Web.UI.UploadedFile postedFile in RadUpload1.UploadedFiles)
        {
            UploadedFileLog.InnerHtml += "<b>Uploaded file information</b>: <hr />";
            UploadedFileLog.InnerHtml += "<b>Nick name</b>: " + NickTextBox.Text;

            if (!Object.Equals(postedFile, null))
            {
                string filname = postedFile.FileName;
                string tim = DateTime.Now.Second.ToString() + "-" + DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString() + "-" + DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString() + "-" + DateTime.Now.Day.ToString() + "-" + DateTime.Now.Month.ToString() + "-" + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();
                postedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/files/test/") + tim + "#" + filname);
                if (postedFile.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    UploadedFileLog.InnerHtml += string.Format("<br /><b>Filename</b>: {0}", postedFile.FileName);
                    UploadedFileLog.InnerHtml += string.Format("<br /><b>File Size</b>: {0} bytes", postedFile.ContentLength);
                }
                else
                {
                    UploadedFileLog.InnerHtml += "<br />No uploaded files yet.";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                UploadedFileLog.InnerHtml += "<br />No uploaded files yet.";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Uploading files generally requires a full postback.

Also, try using RadAsyncUpload, RadUpload has been obsolete for like 2 years now.

You can read up on both things here http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/asyncupload-overview.html

Here is an example:

```
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="Updatepanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <telerik:RadAsyncUpload runat="server" ID="RadAsyncUpload1"></telerik:RadAsyncUpload>
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" Text="work with files" OnClick="Button1_Click" runat="server" />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (UploadedFile file in RadAsyncUpload1.UploadedFiles)
    {
        file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/images/" + file.GetName()), true);
    }
}
```

Of course, add your more complex logic here. Checking for already existing files, creating proper file names, handling user permissions, etc.